# ORA-01427:single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: plsql

I wrote in PL/SQL Developer:

```
select * from lc_history2
```

and I got that error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Can someone help?  It's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Without further information, I can only guess that `lc_history2` is a view that somehow looks like

```
 select 
   c,o,l,u,m,n,s
 from
   table where
     some_column = (select another_column 
              from table
             where something = 'SOMEVALUE')
```

and the inner select returns more than one record for `something = 'SOMEVALUE'`

Comment: so what do i suppose to do?

Comment: Verify if this is the case and if so, adjust the view according to what you want it to return. Maybe, it's sufficient to change the `=` into a `in`, but then again, maybe, it's not.