# ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 10000 bytes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got that error when I tried to execute this query:

```
select *
from lc_history2 lc
where  lc.view_name <> 'LC Main'
and lc.modifiedtime = (select max(modifiedtime) from lc_history2 l where lc.lc = l.lc) 
 and lc.modifiedtime >= sysdate-30
```

Answer (score 7):

`ORU-10027` will appear if you are using a lot of `dbms_output.put_line` in your `PL/SQL` with a small buffer amount. If you are just debugging then you should set this to a large amount (`dbms_output.enable(10000000)` is traditional though from 10g onwards it can be unlimted: `dbms_output.enable(null)`) but try to remove them when going to production.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be using `dbms_output.put_line` in their problem. Maybe their snippet is incomplete?

Comment: From the OP's [previous question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12755) it looks like `lc_history2` is a view, so maybe that calls a function that produces output?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Hmmm so maybe the function is trying to write some output that may or may not be related to the query itself (like debugging statements) and that's failing on a buffer overflow, causing the query on the view to fail with a PL/SQL error... ?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - that's just my guess, but yes. Seems more likely than the posted query being pulled out of a PL/SQL block I think.

Answer (score 4):

If you are executing from a script, you could try adding `set serveroutput on size UNLIMITED` at the begining. Beware though, I don't think the `UNLIMITED` feature is supported in versions of Oracle older than 10 (but I'm not sure, you'll have to test this). If `UNLIMITED` is not supported, just set a very large size.